# Flex objects get sorted automatically

Tags: actionscript-3, sorting, object, apache-flex, datagrid

i am reading a csv file in flex. 
i am using objects to hold name pair values. 
But the problem is the objects get sorted alphabetically and while displaying the csv on the datagrid the column names are sorted.

for eg.

```
    C B A
    1 2 3
    1 2 3
    3 4 5
```

when displaying this on the datagrid it is displayed as

```
    A B C
    3 2 1
    3 2 1
    5 4 3
```

this is my code for reading the object

```
var rowValues:Array = str.split(",");
for(var j:int = 0;j<colname.length;j++)                             
   obj[colname[j]] = rowValues[j];    // the objects get added in alphabetical order here
```

how do i display it as it is, unsorted?

Comment: Would you please share the code how you are reading the csv and converting it into ArrayCollection for the datagrid?

Comment: I resolved the issue. it was my mistake. i loaded the column names into a datagridcolumn object but i didnt set the columns attribute of the datagrid.